# Changing the route to a specific IP adress

Tags: routing, ping

I have the issue of having high ping in an online video game(Final Fantasy XIV), while having normal ping doing anything else. As far as I understand the reason for it is that my router is taking a bad route(much traffic) to the servers of the game.

So my question is how/if I can modify the route my speedport is taking.

Comment: `my router is taking a bad route` no, your router does not determine the full route, every hop along the route determines the next hop, which is beyond your control of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly you don't. Internet, in general, uses "hop-by-hop" routing where the **only part** of the route that's decided by your router is the immediate next hop – which always leads to your ISP. Any further routing is decided by the ISP's router (and by whoever else handles the packet).

Unless *your ISP* notices a problem and reroutes traffic (or some other changes end up reshuffling routes), the only reliable way you can influence the routes is to use some kind of VPN tunnel.

With careful choice of the VPN server, it is technically possible to have both "you→VPN" and "VPN→game" paths being better than the direct one (sometimes, though rarely, even ending up with a shorter path than the direct one).

Comment: Ok, so the only modification I can really do is to change the start of the route. What do I have to be careful about choosing the VPN server?

Comment: Mostly keep trying them until you find noticeable improvement. For example, a tunnel server that's in the same city as the game server, but hosted at a different company, might be one of the things to look for – you're likely to have a different path to it than to the game server (hopefully one that works better), while the path between the two servers in their datacenters is likely to be unnoticeable (in the 1-3ms range), with the end result being a net improvement.

Comment: (Sometimes a commercial VPN service will work, as some of them e.g. WARP are run by companies with _extensive_ connectivity, while at other times you have to rent a cheap VPS server and configure your own VPN through there.)